# Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'any[]'

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-generics

File Name: avatar.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-avatar',
  templateUrl: './avatar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./avatar.component.css']
})
export class AvatarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private dtr: ChangeDetectorRef) { }
  urls: any[] = [];
  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.urls = [] ) {
      this.urls = ['https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png'];
    }
  }
  
  imageFile: any[] = [];
  onSelect(event:any){
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      this.imageFile = event.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
        reader.onload = () => {
         this.urls = reader.result;
              this.dtr.detectChanges();
    }
  }
 }
}
```

File Name: avatar.component.html

```
<div class="container" >
    <img [src]="urls" alt="Avatar" class="image" *ngFor='let url of urls'>
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="onSelect($event)" single>
 </div>
```

I want to display preview of the image and if the image is not selected, then it should be display an Avatar

Answer (score 0):

I just took your instruction and implemented it in Angular:

> I want to display preview of the image and if the image is not selected, then it should be display an avatar.

```js
export class AvatarComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('image') private readonly image!: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;
  protected readonly url$$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_avatar.png');
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const input$ = fromEvent<Event>(this.image.nativeElement, 'change');
    input$
      .pipe(
        map(({ target }) => {
          const file = (<HTMLInputElement>target).files?.[0];
          return file;
        }),
        switchMap((file) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.readAsDataURL(<File>file);
          return fromEvent(reader, 'load');
        }),
        map(({ target }) => (<FileReader>target).result)
      )
      .subscribe((url) => {
        this.url$$.next(<string>url);
      });
  }
}
```

```html
<img [src]="url$$ | async" alt="Avatar" class="image" />
<input type="file" accept="image/*" single #image />
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uunvhx?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Hope that helps.